# How to test simple middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a 3 middlewares like this:

```
module.exports = {

    validateRequest: function(req, res, next) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(!req.body.title || !req.body.location || !req.body.description || !req.body.author){
            Promise.reject('Invalid')
            res.status(errCode.invalid_input).json({
              message: 'Invalid input'
            })
         }
     })
    },
    sendEmail: ...,
    saveToDatabase: ...

}
```

I use those in my route like this:

```
const { validateRequest, sendEmail, saveToDatabase } = require('./create')
...
api.post('/create', validateRequest, sendEmail, saveToDatabase);
```

It works, but I can't test it. Here's my (failed) attempt:

```
test('create.validateRequest should throw error if incorrect user inputs', (done) => {
  const next = jest.fn();
  const req = httpMocks.createRequest({ 
    body: { 
            title: 'A new world!',
            location: '...bunch of talks...',
            description: '...'  
    }
  });
  const res = httpMocks.createResponse();
  expect(validateRequest(req, res, next)).rejects.toEqual('Invalid')

})
```

**Jest outputs this:

Error

   Invalid**

> Question: How can I test this validateRequest middleware?

Comment: Is that an example of real code? Cos you have a bit of an anti-pattern going on.

Comment: Yes it is. Can you point out what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly, assuming this is Express, there's no reason (or requirement) to return a `Promise` from your middleware, return values are ignored. Secondly, your current code will actually cause valid requests to hang because you aren't calling `next` to propagate the request to the next middleware.

Taking this into account, your middleware should look a bit more like

```
validateRequest: (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.title || !req.body.location || !req.body.description || !req.body.author) {
    // end the request
    res.status(errCode.invalid_input).json({
      message: 'Invalid input'
    });
  } else {
    // process the next middleware
    next();
  }
},
```

Based on the above, a valid unit test would look like

```
test('create.validateRequest should throw error if incorrect user inputs', () => {
  const next = jest.fn();
  const req = httpMocks.createRequest({ 
    body: { 
      title: 'A new world!',
      location: '...bunch of talks...',
      description: '...'  
    }
  });
  const res = httpMocks.createResponse();
  validateRequest(req, res, next);
  // validate HTTP result
  expect(res.statusCode).toBe(400);
  expect(res._isJSON()).toBeTruthy();
  // validate message
  const json = JSON.parse(res._getData());
  expect(json.message).toBe('Invalid input');
})
```

Comment: Where we can get the `httpMocks.createResponse()` and `httpMokcs.createRequest()` ?

Comment: @dennbagas I could be wrong but the syntax lends itself to [node-mocks-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http).